# MaxCounters (lesson 4 in codility) - 100% correctness but 60% on efficiency, why?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance

[Link to the problem](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/max_counters/)

In a nutshell:

- `N` is an integer that represents a number of counters and the max counter allowed;
- `A` is an array that represents the operation done on a specific counter (for example, if `A[0]` is `1` and `N` is `3`, we need to add `1` to `counter[0]`);
- If an element in `A` is `N+1`, all elements of the `counter` should be changed to the largest number in the `counter` array.

I submitted the code I wrote and got only 60% in performance. Why is that? Any way I should approach a problem next time to make it more efficient? How can I improve?

```js
function solution(N,A){

    let counters = Array(N).fill(0);
    let maxCounter = 0;
    for(i=0;i<A.length;i++){
        if(A[i]<=N){
            counters[A[i]-1]++
            if(counters[A[i]-1]>maxCounter){maxCounter = counters[A[i]-1]};
        }
        else if(A[i]===N+1){
            counters = Array(N).fill(maxCounter)
        }
    }
    return counters
}
```

Edit: I didn't know that this website wasn't meant for questions regarding code improvement, thanks, I will ask somewhere else.

Comment: this is better suited to post on reddit, stackoverflow isnt really meant for these sort of questions (at least i dont think they are)

Comment: We fix broken code, you need to go to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if you have working code that you want to improve upon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `60%` score for efficiency is because of the two last test cases where over `10,000` *"max counter"* operations get performed. https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingA86B4F-NDB/

Each of those operations has to iterate through the `counter` array, which may have as many as `100,000` elements. That works out to a total of `1 billion` writes, so the reason for the performance problem comes quickly in sight.

To improve this and bring this number down, we can eliminate the needless consecutive *"max counter"* operations by, for example, introducing a flag denoting whether the `counter` array is already maxed and there is no need to iterate through it all over again.

Sample code:

```js
const solution = (n, arr) => {
  const counter = new Array(n).fill(0);
  let max = 0, counterMaxed = false;

  for (let curr of arr) {
    if (curr > n) {
      if (!counterMaxed) { counter.fill(max); counterMaxed = true; }
      continue;
    }

    curr--; counter[curr]++; counterMaxed = false;
    if (counter[curr] > max) { max = counter[curr]; }
  }

  return counter;
};
```

This gets a straight `100%` score:
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training3H48RM-6EG/

Answer (score 0):

One possible improvement would be, when you need to fill the whole array with the new max counters, don't create an entirely new array to do so - instead, change the existing array.

```
else if(A[i]===N+1){
    counters.fill(maxCounter)
}
```

This could have a large effect if there are a whole lot of counters.

Comment: It helped a little bit, but I still get same performance score of 60%.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using object which will generate the actual array only once (after all operations are applied).

The "tracker" object will only ever hold the indices & values of those counters which have an operation. Say, N (ie, "num" number of counters) is 50,000 but only 5,000 counters have an explicit operation in A (ie, "arr" array), only those 5,000 elements will be *tracked* (using the "tracker" object).

**Code Snippet**

```js
// alternative solution using object
const counterOps = (num, arr) => {
  // the "tracker" object we will use to populate the result array
  const tracker = {};
  
  // when "num+1" to reset all elements to "max", then
  // the "max" value is stored in "lastMaxSet"
  let lastMaxSet = 0;
  
  // helper method to get current max from "tracker"
  const getMax = obj => Math.max(...Object.values(obj));
  
  // helper method to "set" "all" values to "max"
  const setMax = obj => {
    lastMaxSet = getMax(obj);
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => obj[k] = lastMaxSet);
  };
  
  // iterate through "arr" and "apply" each "operation"
  arr.forEach(elt => {
    if (elt === num + 1) {
      // "reset to max" operation is applied
      setMax(tracker);
    } else {
      // a particular counter is incremented
      const k = elt - 1;
      tracker[k] ??= lastMaxSet;
      tracker[k]++;
    }
  });
  
  // the "tracker" object is used to generate
  // the result-array on-the-fly
  return [...Array(num).fill(lastMaxSet)].map(
    (val, idx) => idx in tracker ? tracker[idx] : val
  );
};

console.log(counterOps(5, [3, 4, 4, 6, 1, 4, 4]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Please try out and share feedback if it helped at all (with performance).